# Yii GroupGridView buttons

Tags: yii, crud

I use [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/groupgridview) extension(GroupGridView) in my yii project.
Now, I need help. How to add crud buttons for the grouped elements, to get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know is it right sollution.
I've created component GroupButtonColumn:

```
class GroupButtonColumn extends CButtonColumn {
public $name = 'buttons';
public $value; }
```

And my view

```
$this->widget('ext.groupGridView.GroupGridView', array(
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'summaryText' => false,
'filter' => $model,
'mergeColumns' => ['t_id', 'buttons'],
'columns' => [
    [
        'name' => 't_id',
        'header' => '№',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->t_id, ["/task/view", "id"=>$data->t_id])',
        'filter' => false,
        'type' => 'raw'
    ],
    /* ... */
    [
        'class' => 'GroupButtonColumn',
        'template' => '{update}, {delete}',
        'buttons' => [
            'update' => [
                'url' => '$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/task/update", array("id"=>$data->t_id))'
            ],
            'delete' => [
                'url' => '$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/task/delete", array("id"=>$data->t_id))'
            ]
        ]
    ],
],
```

));

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
'mergeColumns' => array('project_id', 'project_id')
/* ... */
'columns' => [
    'project_id',
    'id',
    /* ... */
   [
    'name' => 'project_id',
    'header' => 'Action',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value' => function($data){
         return '<a href="/?project_id='.$data->project_id.'" class="btn btn-primary">Start</a>';
     }
   ],
```